# split email from string with PHP

Tags: php

I need to be able to split a string that contains email's `From` information. From the string I need to extract `$NAME` and `$EMAIL` or whatever is available.

The string can be in the following formats:

```
"Santa Clause" <santa@example.com>

Santa Clause <santa@example.com>

<santa@example.com>
```

Comment: Please add more information about what a string can look like (in full) and what result you need.

Comment: The only tip I can give with that limited information is use a regular expression with the preg_match function.

Comment: Sorry, when I posted originally I did not realize my example was "cleaned up" by the site. I was able to get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string_to_check = '"Santa Clause" <santa@npole.com>'
$matches = array();
preg_match('/?([^<"]*)"?\s*<(\S*)>/',$string_to_check,$matches);
$matches[1] //=> Santa Claus
$matches[2] //=> santa@npole.com
```

Comment: $string_to_check in the preg_match function would be $string_to_match here. Also, preg_math => preg_match.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('#(?:"(?<name>[^"]+)"|(?<name>.+))?<(?<email>.+)>#U', $string, $matches);
echo var_dump($matches);

preg_match('#(?:"(?<name>[^"]+)"|(?<name>.+))?<(?<email>[^>]+)>#U', $string, $matches);
echo var_dump($matches);
```

Try one of the above. The former will allow more valid emails, whereas the latter is faster.

Answer (score 0):

If the separator is always the same character (e.g. the semicolon):

```
$items = explode($separator, $from);
```

Otherwise, browse around in the `preg_XXX` functions for regex-based string splitting.

Answer (score 0):

For the mail adress, have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. This is a function that matches a string against a regular expression. [Here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/regular-expressions-php)'s a short intro into how to use regular expressions with PHP.

If you want to match the name also, it will be some effort, so I suggest you first develop a regular expression that can extract an email address out of your string and then augment it to find the name also.

Answer (score 0):

Found this and it works great!

```
$parts = preg_split('/[\'"<>]( *[\'"<>])*/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```